# Do an update and after a delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, bdd

I've had a problem that's been bothering me for a long time now.
I have a database in MariaBD (with WAMP) and an API in expressjs.
In my database, I have two tables: table "menu" and table "item" with foreign key on a menu.

I want to make an update on all the items and set the foreign key field to null.
And only afterwards, delete the menu.

The problem is that the update doesn't finish fast enough, and my function tries to delete the menu at the same time (which is not possible because of the foreign keys).

I've tried with Promise and async/await, but neither of them let me wait long enough.

Any ideas?

My code without async/await:

```
router.delete('/delete/:menuId', function (req, res, next) {
  return Item.findAll({
      where: {
        menuId: req.params.menuId,
      },
    })
    .then(
      itemsFounded => {
        //Unlink items / menu
        itemsFounded.forEach(element => {
          element.update({
            menuId: null
          })
        });
        //Then destroy menu
        Menu.destroy({
          where: {
            id: menuId
          }
        }).then(() => {
          return res / status(200);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(400);
        })
      }
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).send(error)
    });
});
```

My code with async/await (sorry if it's illegible, I'm not used to it):

```
router.delete('/delete/:menuId', async function (req, res, next) {
  return Item.findAll({
      where: {
        menuId: req.params.menuId,
      },
    })
    .then(
      async itemsFounded => {
        //Unlink items / menu
        const result = await getResult(itemsFounded, req.params.menuId);
        if (result === true) {
          console.log("result est true")
          return res.status(200);
        } else {
          console.log("result est false")
          return res.status(400).send("error");
        }
      }
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).send(error)
    });
});

async function getResult(itemsFounded, menuId) {
  console.log("In getResult");
  const result = await destroyMenu(itemsFounded, menuId);
  console.log("Result of destroyMenu : " + result);
  return result;
}

async function destroyMenu(itemsFounded, menuId) {
  console.log("Start destroyMenu");
  const result = await updateItems(itemsFounded);
  console.log("updateItems() : " + result);
  console.log("updateItems OK");
  Menu.destroy({
    where: {
      id: menuId
    }
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("In menu.destroy");
    return true;
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error in menu.destroy");
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  })
}

async function updateItems(itemsFounded) {
  console.log("in updateItems");
  itemsFounded.forEach(element => {
    element.update({
      menuId: null
    })
  });
  return true;
}
```

And the result of console :

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `description`, `picture`, `price`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `menuId` FROM `items` AS `item` WHERE `item`.`menuId` = '1';
In getResult
Start destroyMenu
in updateItems
Executing (default): UPDATE `items` SET `menuId`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?
Executing (default): UPDATE `items` SET `menuId`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?
Executing (default): UPDATE `items` SET `menuId`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?
updateItems() : [object SequelizeInstance:item],[object SequelizeInstance:item],[object SequelizeInstance:item]
updateItems OK
Result of destroyMenu : undefined
result est false
DELETE /api/menu/delete/1 400 365.422 ms - 5
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `menus` WHERE `id` = '1'
In menu.destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `forEach`-loop and inside you are performing the asynchronous updates. The execution of your code will immediately execute the next statement after iterating through the loop, i.e. it will not wait for the updates to finish.

You can fix this by using a regular for-loop and `async/await`:

```
async function updateItems(itemsFound) {
  for(const foundItem of itemsFound) {
    await foundItem.update({
      menuId: null
    })
  });
}
```

An alternative is to use `Promise.all()` if you want to do the update in parallel and not in sequence:

```
async function updateItems(itemsFound) {
  return Promise.all(itemsFound.map(foundItem => foundItem.update({ menuId: null}) );
}
```

With either solution, you now simply have to make sure to await `updateItems` when calling it:

```
// ... find items
await updateItems(...);
// ... delete menu
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! 
Would it be the same problem for the Menu.destroy()? Looking at the logs, the destroy is executed after the end of the request (I updated my code to show the console.log) :

Comment: Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `description`, `picture`, `price`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `menuId` FROM `items` AS `item` WHERE `item`.`menuId` = '1';
In getResult
Start destroyMenu
in updateItems
Executing (default): UPDATE `items` SET `menuId`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `id` = ?
updateItems() : [object SequelizeInstance:item],[object SequelizeInstance:item]
updateItems OK
Result of destroyMenu : undefined
result est false
DELETE /api/menu/delete/1 400 365.422 ms - 5
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `menus` WHERE `id` = '1'
In menu.destroy